# обрисовывание 3D модели

Tags: нейронные-сети, 3d, 2d, рисование

Мне стало интересно, можно ли с помощью нейросети формировать рисунок на основе кадра, на котором изображена 3D-модель. Что-то вроде того, что на рисунке. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня идея только одна - набрать примитивов линий, а потом пытаться аппроксимировать 3D модель набором этих примитивов, есть ли ещё какие-либо подходы к решению этой проблемы?

Comment: Для этих целей хорошо подходит "классическая механика".  Делается с помощью применения различных шейдеров. В sdk DirectX есть похожий пример (если ничего не путаю)

Comment: а насколько реалистично выглядит результат?

Comment: Просто не хотелось бы получить в итоге молельки из Ниндзя Бэтмэна

Comment: http://www.unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=38806 может что найдёте похожее

Comment: спасибо за помощь, тут идея не в простом обрисовывании, а в имитации рисования с нуля, как на прикреплённом изображении